# Bash script with OR condition

Tags: linux, bash

Hoping someone here can help me with a bash script that runs only on certain conditions.

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
MODE=$1
if  [ $(date '+%A') == "Sunday" ] || [ $(date '+%d') == "01" ] || [ $MODE == 'Complete']
then
    echo "Running backup as it is the either a Sunday the 1st of the Month or the script was called with the paramater 'Complete'."
    /usr/bin/7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 /external-storage/snapshots/snapshot-complete-"$TODAY"-public_html.7z /local-storage/www/public_html > /dev/null
fi
```

When I try to run the above I get the error.

```
line 4: [: missing `]'
```

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
MODE=$1
DAY=$(date '+%A')
DATE=$(date '+%d')
if  [[  ($DAY == "Sunday")   ||  ($DATE == "01")  ||  ($MODE == "Complete") ]] ; then
    echo "Running backup as it is the either a Sunday the 1st of the Month or the script
    was called with the parameter 'Complete'."
 ...................
fi
```

Some parentheses are there only for clarity.

But you should be careful, **your test does not** mirror what your echo statement affirms. The test evaluates to a positive for ANY Sunday, not just the first of the month.

Answer (score 1):

The `]` is special and needs to be on its own. You're missing a space before the last one.

So line 4 should be:

```
if  [ $(date '+%A') == "Sunday" ] || [ $(date '+%d') == "01" ] || [ $MODE == 'Complete' ]
```